# can't update a field(column in a table) using datediff in the 'where' part

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to update a field in a table only if it has been a month from the last update.

I tried:

```
update studentClasses set lastCharge = getDate(), classBalance = classBalance - Price
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, classBalance.lastCharge , GETDATE()) = 1
AND classBalance.endDate < GETDATE()
```

Didn't work.. :(

Is anyone know how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

(I'm using sql server 2008 express)

Comment: I don't think `DATEDIFF(month,...` does what you expect. Read the manual. (it counts the number of monthbounderies). Use DATEDIFF(day...) = 30 or even better `endDate = DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `classBalance` as both a table and a column in the `studentClasses` table.
Maybe try:

```
update studentClasses set lastCharge = getDate(), classBalance = classBalance - Price
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, lastCharge , GETDATE()) = 1
AND endDate < GETDATE()
```

(assuming `endDate` and `Price` are in `studentClasses` and `classBalance` is a column, not a table)